# O que é eth0, wlan0, wlo1?

Tags: linux, redes

Sempre vejo no Linux, quando digito o comando `ifconfig`, uns nomes do tipo eth0, eno1, lo, wlan1, wlo1. O que eles significam?

Answer (score 5):

[`ifconfig`](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig), acrônimo de “*Interface Configuration*”: É uma das ferramentas mais utilizadas nos sistemas Linux para configurar, adicionar, deletar e gerenciar as interfaces de rede do sistema.

Quando você quer exibir as configurações de rede você digita `ifconfig` e obtém algo do tipo:

```
[root@linux ~]# ifconfig

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1B:B9:B3:BD:4F
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
          Interrupt:201 Base address:0xc00

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:9439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:9439 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:5524963 (5.2 MiB)  TX bytes:5524963 (5.2 MiB)
```

Isso significa:

- `ethX`: placa de rede Ethernet
- `lo`: interface [loopback](http://www.bosontreinamentos.com.br/redes-computadores/o-que-e-uma-interface-de-loopback/)

No Linux, as placas Ethernet cabeadas recebem nomes como `eth0` (primeira placa), `eth1` (segunda placa), `eth2` (terceira placa) e assim por diante. No caso das placas wireless, o nome muda de acordo com o modelo e com o driver usado. Placas configuradas através do ndiswrapper são identificadas como `wlan0`, placas com chipset Ralink como `ra0` e placas com chipset Intel como `eth1`, da mesma forma que uma placa cabeada.